# Redirect out of login page if session alive

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

in my laravel application, there is something strange happening, i had the idea when a user have a active session, some how the app didnt let the user go the the login page form. For example if im logged in to my app, and then go to login page, i expect that im redirect to the dashboard since i have a live session.

What is wrong?

My routes:

```
// Login and Dashboard route
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@getIndex');
Route::get('dashboard', 'MainController@getDashboard');

//Authentication Routes
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');
```

My laravel version is 5.2

Comment: The app is redirecting you to the dashboard if you go to the login page while you are logged in?

Comment: Use `Auth::check()` in route.

This will help you http://laravelbook.com/laravel-user-authentication/

Comment: If you add a `Route::group(["middleware" => "guest"], function(){ ... });` around your `auth/login` routes, it will auto redirect you away from login if you're logged in.

Answer (score -1):

You can control the redirect after login in app/Http/Controller/Auth/AuthController.php by changing the $redirectTo string.

```
protected $redirectTo = 'dashboard';
```

You can control the redirect from /login when you have an active session in app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php. If you want to show the login page with an active session you could comment `return redirect('your/route');`

Comment: you dont understood the question, im not asking after i login, im asking when i have a active session, so this means i already logged in before.

Comment: You can change that in app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php